# Scale div inside another div with overflow scroll and center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm coding a very tiny small feature, but I'm having problems with the scroll. I need to do a zoom of a div scaling with css:

```
transform: scale(X,Y)
```

But my problem is that I don't have a correct left and top scroll in the parent div. I need to know how to calculate the new left and top each time the user press the button "More zoom", I could use translate css property if it is mandatory.

I can use jQuery, but I think this is just a math problem :)

**One detail:** I need that the image grow from the center.

Picture:

[image]

Here is the fiddle:

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/as20h6t4/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i believe you need to mind transform-origin too:

```js
// get element references
var foo = document.querySelector('#foo');
var bar = document.querySelector('#bar');

// fit bar into foo
// the third options argument is optional, see the README for defaults
// https://github.com/soulwire/fit.js


var zoom = 1;
var trans = 50;
var moreZoom = document.querySelector('#moreZoom');
moreZoom.onclick = function(e){
console.log(foo);
     bar.style.transform = 'scale(' + (zoom + 0.1) + ',' + (zoom + 0.1) + ')';
     zoom = (zoom + 0.1);
     bar.style.transformOrigin = (50 / zoom) +'px  ' +(50 / zoom )+'px';
}
```

```css
#foo {
    background: #36D7B7;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 50px;
     overflow: auto;
    
}
#bar {
    background-image: url('http://www.space.com/images/i/000/028/001/original/wing-small-magellanic-cloud-galaxy-1920.jpg?interpolation=lanczos-none&fit=around%7C1440:900&crop=1440:900;*,*');
    background-size:cover;
    height: 100%;
    transform:scale(1);
    width: 100%;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/soulwire/fit.js/master/fit.js"></script>
<button id="moreZoom">
More Zoom
</button>

<div id="foo">
    <div
```

http://jsfiddle.net/as20h6t4/5/

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but the image is not growing from the center... Maybe I should add in my question. Sorry.

Comment: @chemitaxis at one point it must be growing from top left, else part of it won't be reachable :) . you can also use transform-origin:0 0; and reset the scrollbar position

Comment: Thanks, I have tested better in my computer and this is correct ;) Thank you so much